# Build Typo3 links from a Link-Type field

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a link-type field in the backend. This stores the information like this:

"3 _blank" <----- for internal pages

"http://www.google.com _blank"  <--- for external pages

How can I build links in Typoscript, using this values? Common typolink technique wont apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will apply put these values as typolink's parameter

```
lib.mylink = TEXT
lib.mylink.parameter = 3 _blank
```

It will create a link to page

```
<a href="index.php?id=3" target="_blank">Page title here</a>
```